# Site redirects to /Login method after successfull authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Im developing an MVC 5.0 .ASP NET app. Im using Identity to authorize users. I've added another method to AccountController where user can log in with Token. After 'signing in' in my method instead of rendering chosen view application redirects to default login method. When you type mysite/home/ it shows that user is logged in.
I can't find when the redirect to Login is made.
Any ideas how to fix this?

To authenticate user in my action I use this method:

```
   private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
        }
```

My custom login action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginWithToken(string token, string returnUrl)
    {
        AccountService accountService = new AccountService(db);
        string userId;
        try
        {
            userId = await accountService.GetUserIdFromToken(token);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError(exception.Message, exception);
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    try
    {
        await SignInAsync(user, false);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Logowanie nieudane. Konto mogło zostać zablokowane lub usunięte. Skontaktuj się  z administratorem serwisu.", new AccessViolationException());

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    LogUserLogin(user.UserName, Request.UserHostAddress);

    string decodedUrl = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);



    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))
    {
        return View((object)decodedUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index", new { });
    }

}
```

EDIT:
I've found out that when my method is hitting  return View((object)decodedUrl); request doesn't contains ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie". I've set breakpoint on Application_BeginRequest and right after renturn View((object)decodedUrl) there is request to Login action. At this point there is ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" in request.

Comment: and where do you perform the redirect?

Comment: First I've tried to redirect using Redirect("/Controller/Action"). It didn't worked. Now pass url to view assigned to action. In View I make redirect using windows.location =  url.

Comment: I forgot to mention that after redirecting me to Login action "LoginWithToken?token=1234&returnUrl=someAction/" is set as returnUrl parameter.

Comment: That means you executed `LoginWithToken` but were redirected back to `Login`. You have put a breakpoint on that action and stepped through it? There are a couple paths that would lead you back to `Login`.

Comment: LoginWithToken goes right to the return View((object)decodedUrl);

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found that the authentication cookie wasn't set to the current request but to next request.
Now my LoginWithToken Method redirects to another [AllowAnonymous] Action so the cookie is set. Then that action redirects to authorisation restricted areas.